# (java.net.ProtocolException) Unable to stream video in video view. (Video which was trimmed using FFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, stream, android-videoview

Hello I am using the below command to trim video using FFmpeg (trim without re-encoding)

```
String[] command = new String[]{"-y", "-i", original_path, "-ss", ""+ startMs / 1000, "-t" , "" +((endMs - startMs) / 1000), "-c", "copy", dest.getPath()};
```

Now this trimmed video is present on my server but i am not able to stream it in video view. Whereas I can play the other videos which was not trimmed using FFmpeg.

Below is the code load video in videoview

```
VideoView videov = findViewById(R.id.videov);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://x.x.xxxx.xxxx:8000/xxxxxApp/media/xxxx/1608121174332.mp4");
videov.setVideoURI(uri);
videov.start();
```

Also I can play the same video in webview control.

Comment: Couldn't open  http://x.x.xxxx.xxxx:8000/xxxxxApp/media/xxxx/1608121174332.mp4:java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://x.x.xxxx.xxxx:8000/xxxxxApp/media/xxxx/1608121174332.mp4

Comment: are you running app in Android emulator and video is from local drive(from your pc/laptop)??

Comment: @VivekThummar. I am running app on real device using video url. As mentioned in question.